# How to decode an UTF-8 encoded API response

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

When I send a request to an `API`:

```py
import requests

url = 'website'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url.strip(), headers=headers, timeout=10)
response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding
print(response.text)
```

The output is:

```py
0e1\u10e2\u10d4\u10db\u10d0 BOSE,\u10d3\u10d0\u10ec\u10e7\u10d4\u10d1\u10d0-\u10d2\u10d0\u10e9\u10d4\u10e0\u10d4\u10d1\u10d8\u10e1 \u10e1\u10d8\u10e1\u10e2\u10d4\u10db\u10d0,\u10d4\u10da\u10d4\u10e5\u10e2\u10e0\u10dd\u10dc\u10e3\u10da\u10d8 \u10d3\u10d8\u10e4\u10d4\u10e0\u10d4\u10dc\u10ea\u10d8\u10d0\u10da\u10e3\u10e0\u10d8 \u10e1\u10d0\u10d9\u10d4\u10e2\u10d8,\u10eb\u10e0\u10d0\u10d5\u10d8\u10e1 \u10e1\u10d0\u10db\u10e3\u10ee\u10e0\u10e3\u10ed\u10d4 \u10d9\u10dd\u10dc\u10e2\u10e0\u10dd\u10da\u10d8\u10e1 \u10e1\u10d8\u10e1\u10e2\u10d4\u10db\u10d0,\u10ec\u10d4\u10d5\u10d8\u10e1 \u10d9\u10dd\u10dc\u10e2\u10e0\u10dd\u10da\u10d8\u10e1 \u10e1\u10d8\u10e1\u10e2\u10d4\u10db\u10d0,\u10e1\u10e2\u10d0\u10d1\u10d8\u10da\u10e3\u10e0\u10dd\u10d1\u10d8\u10e1 \u10e1\u10d8\u10e1\u10e2\u10d4\u10db\u10d0,\u10d3\u10d0\u10d1\u10da\u10dd\u10d9\u10d5\u10d8\u10e1 \u10e1\u10d0\u10ec\u10d8\u10dc\u10d0\u10d0\u10e6\u10db\u10d3\u10d4\u10d2\u10dd \u10d3\u10d0\u10db\u10e3\u10ee\u10e0\u10e3\u10ed\u10d4\u10d
```

How to decode it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In order to encode or decode from utf8 string you can use :

```py
s = "test"
u = s.encode("utf8")
s = u.decode("utf8")
```

But your problem is that your string is utf-8 encoded **and escaped**!
So you will need to **un-escape** it and then re-interpret it:

```py
s = response.text
r = s.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')
print(r)
# -> '0e1ტემა BOSE,დაწყება-გაჩერების სისტემა,ელექტრონული დიფერენციალური საკეტი,ძრავის სამუხრუჭე კონტროლის სისტემა,წევის კონტროლის სისტემა,სტაბილურობის სისტემა,დაბლოკვის საწინააღმდეგო დამუხრუჭებ'
```